# Playstore Accessibility Preflight Results for Multiple Apps

Tags: google-play-developer-api, accessibility

I am trying to see if there is a way to access the Preflight accessibility results for all of my apps.

I can access each on individually but since my publisher account manages many apps it is tedious to do it that way.

Thanks!